# Indy 10 in Lazarus RingCentral API RingOut TIdHTTP

Tags: indy, lazarus, ringcentral

Lazarus 1.8.4
Indy 10 (March 2020)
Windows Server 2016

I'm trying to build a little "Dialer" module for a contact list I've built in Lazarus.  After fiddling for months, I was finally able to translate all the RingCentral API settings into Postman, then into Indy HTTP settings, to accomplish obtaining a token.  That part works reliably. However, I am unable to do a RingOut API.  I always get 404 not found. The examples in other programming languages given by RingCentral in their docs don't translate well into Indy.

```
if htpCall.Connected then
  htpCall.Request.Connection := 'close';  // Close the socket after using it to obtain the token
htpCall.Request.Clear;

htpCall.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
htpCall.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
htpCall.Request.Username := '<redacted>';   // Client ID
htpCall.Request.Password := '<redacted>';   //  Client Secret
htpCall.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
htpCall.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := False;
htpCall.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
htpCall.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + acc_tkn);

prms_lst.Add('from=<redacted>');
prms_lst.Add('to=<redacted>');
prms_lst.Add('callerId=<redacted>');
prms_lst.Add('country=Canada');
prms_lst.Add('playPrompt=true');

// Remove the text ".devtest" for the production version of your code, and replace the phone account with the real main phone number
htpCall.Post('https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/<redacted>/extension/101/ring-out', prms_lst);
```

UPDATE:

If I leave the TIdHTTP open, then run the code above, I get a different error.

Sent:

```
POST /restapi/v1.0/account//extension/101/ring-out HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 82
Authorization: Basic 
Host: platform.devtest.ringcentral.com
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)


from=&to=&callerId=&country=Canada&playPrompt=true
```

Rcvd:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 25 Aug 2020 01:50:24 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 175
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="RingCentral REST API"
RCRequestId: 57c97008-e675-11ea-87cf-005056bb81b6

{
  "errorCode" : "AGW-402",
  "message" : "Invalid Authorization header",
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorCode" : "AGW-402",
    "message" : "Invalid Authorization header"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Offering to pay for work (whether monetarily or in trade) is inappropriate here. The site guidelines require that all questions be asked and answered here, and that all interactions occur here, and that people contribute freely and voluntarily. If you have a specific question related to your own code, ask it. Other requests (*if you have an example sitting around* or *I'll pay for a solution*) are not acceptable.

Comment: If you have information to add to your question, do so with an [edit] to the question instead of posting it in comments. Right now, you're just creating unreadable noise and clutter (which is causing me to get notified, which is getting annoying :-)). You *really* should read the [help] pages.

Comment: @user3319732 The `POST` request you have shown is completely malformed. It claims the `Content-Type` is `application/json`, but the body data is not JSON at all. You can't use a `TStringList` to post JSON, use need to use a `TStream` instead, like `TStringStream`. Also, the request claims the `Content-Length` is 82, but the body data shown is 50 (I assume the redacted data accounts for the missing length?). And the `Authorization` header is incomplete, it is missing all credential data (which is what the server error is complaining about), and doesn't even match the code you have shown.

Comment: @user3319732 on a side note, setting `htpCall.Request.Connection := 'close'` and then calling `htpCall.Request.Clear()` afterwards will reset the `Connection` to a blank string.

Comment: 1) About TStringList:  This method works for getting a Token (in Lazarus) and is what I assumed is used in Postman, that's why I thought I could use it for calling a RingOut.  But I will try the JSON method mentioned
2) There is no Authorization field in TIdHTTP, that is why I had to add it myself using htpCall.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + acc_tkn);  I suspect the server complains, so the HTTP reverts to "Basic" then is missing the token bc Basic is set to False for the RingOut call.
3) Closing the connection prior to Ringout causes 404 I have to leave it open

Comment: @user3319732 "*There is no Authorization field in TIdHTTP*" - yes, there is: the `TIdHTTP.Request.Authentication` property. But it is not a simple `string`, it is a `TIdAuthentication` object that you have to assign. Indy has some pre-defined classes (`TIdBasicAuthentication`, etc), but does not have a class for `Bearer` at this time, but you can easily write your own. Otherwise `CustomHeaders` will work fine, just be sure that `TIdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication` is False. `TIdHTTP` will not revert to `Basic` unless `BasicAuthentication` is True.